# Mail not sent to contact in journey in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, help, sfmcadmin

For a subscriber in our marketing cloud org, email is not being sent even after it has successfully entered the journey. Subscriber is not in unsubscribed or held status. Subscriber does not belong to any suppression lists as well.

Also there are other customers with the same domain who receive emails without any issues.

Anyone knows possible reasons?

Answer (score 1):

A few other possibilities:

**Hidden Triggered Send Managed List**.

This is not a list that's visible in the UI and is populated when a triggered send does not use a list. It's possible to be marked as Held here and not for the same SubscriberKey in All Subscribers. The backend Marketing Cloud SubscriberId will likely be different to the one linked to the record for the SubscriberKey in All Subscribers, so if this is the issue, it's vital that you follow the steps in Salesforce's guide on this so you isolate the correct record to delete (which will in turn allow emails to be sent to the remaining record, assuming it meets all other criteria): https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381035&type=1

**Auto-Suppression Configuration**

I know you have mentioned that the Subscriber is not on any suppression lists, so this may not apply, but it's worth checking.

**ListDetective**

This is a proprietary list of 'bad' email addresses that Marketing Cloud automatically will not send to. I've seen cases of perfectly legitimate email addresses featuring here because of certain strings appearing in the email address, such as 'spam'. Marketing Cloud Support can assist if the email address has been excluded for this reason.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387004&type=1

**Other checks**

If you are also using the Transactional Messaging API to send transactional emails, there's a lot of information available for delivery errors, either via the Not Sent tab in the Email's 'View Details' section, or via the Event Notification Service (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ens.html) which can be excellent for troubleshooting cases like this.

However, it's also worth talking to Marketing Cloud Support as they may have access to more detailed back-end logs and may assist you in finding a root cause.